# Allow User login to two different apps

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Hello: I already have a live production app on parse.com and I am about to submit my second app to apple store. I want to allow single user to login in to my two different apps? Similar to single sign on. If user has already signed up with one app then he/she can use the same login name to sign in to my another app. Can this be done? and how? I am here at the fork deciding which way to go. Should I create two separate apps on parse.com? or should I share the space with my new app? What are the downstream effects on push notifications because both of my apps support push notifications. Can anyone please help me with this dilemma? 
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: One of the Parse developers answered this question on their support board. Looks like it's not possible. https://www.parse.com/questions/can-multiple-ios-apps-share-a-single-user-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that this is your question.

`Is it possible to allow a user to log into two apps with the same username and password? If so, then how?`

The answer to this is yes, it is definitely possible. There are quite a few ways to achieve this.

One way is to incorporate "Sign in with Google" which Google allows through their API. You would have to integrate their API for that. There may be other 3rd party APIs that allow you to achieve this as well.

However, If you want the username and passwords to be specific for your apps, then you will definitely have to store them in the cloud. This means that you would need a back end web server with a database where, just to state the bare bones, you would store the username and password and any related information.

Both apps would check the same database for usernames and passwords. This is the basic idea behind having multiple apps log in with the same credentials.

Comment: How about FB and twitter login for the above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make communication between both of your apps using [Internation Communication By Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2)

> URL scheme lets you communicate with other apps by defining protocol as your own. To communicate with an app that implements such a
>   scheme, you must create an appropriately formatted URL and ask the
>   system to open it. To implement support for a custom scheme, you must
>   declare support for the scheme and handle incoming URLs that use the
>   scheme.

Hope its clear and useful to you.